# How to stop a Db2 instance properly?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a Db2 instance, and I need to stop it properly, clean, without using `db2stop force`. I need this in order to restart it fast in a batch process.

I am completly sure there are no connections or active databases; however, the instance does not stop. Attached, there is an image that shows this behaviour.

[image]

What can I do? What is using the instance that produces the SQL1025 error?

Comment: Have you tried quiesce?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate all active databases first, in your case

```
db2 deactivate db
```

before stopping the instance. `db2stop force` does that for you, so I'm not sure what's wrong with simply using the `force` option.